# Trying to position an icon to align with the first line of text in a two line span element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a container in a react app that has an icon and a span element.

I'm trying to align the icon with the first line of text in the span element, and have the second line of text break and start on the next line.

I currently have the icon lined up with the text in the span element but the problem is that no matter what I use, including `overflowWrap: 'break-word'`, the text in the span element all stays on one line.

I have the HTML for the container below along with the styling and I've included a CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit beautiful-snow-04ky6]

`HTML`

```
<AddressContainer>
  <MapIcon />
    <Address>
        {location.address.addressLine1} {location.address.addressLine2 
        {location.address.city}, {location.address.state} {location.address.zip5}
    </Address>
</AddressContainer>
```

`CSS`

```
const AddressContainer = styled('div')({
  color: 'black',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
});

const Address = styled('span')({
  overflowWrap: 'break-word'
})
```

Comment: Are you able to add a <br> tag in the text?

Comment: Can you provide the **output** HTML & CSS in a Snippet?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeup, I just added a CodeSandbox that shows the issue. @Dylan when I added the ```<br />``` it repositions all of the elements so that the icon is no longer aligned with the first line of text

Answer (score 0):

Put you `MapIcon` tag inside of your `Address` tag like this:

```
<Address><MapIcon/> 999 Fiction Ave TownCity, CA 12345</Address>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get the second line of text to line up to right under the 999 Fiction in line one?

Comment: Add `textAlign: "left"` to your Address span

Comment: Ah I tried that, but when the window size is reduced the icon is aligned at the center between the two lines instead of staying in line with the top line of text

Comment: Really? That's weird. Because this is the result I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USZZM.png. Did you put the MapIcon tag in your Address tag like mentioned in my answer?

Comment: That partially works but I'm trying to get that second line of text to line up right underneath the first line of text instead of starting at the bottom of the MapIcon